How to use curl option "--cert-type P12 --cert certificate.pfx:xxxxxx" in Axios?
I have the curl command bellow that makes a https request with a pfx certificate.
@echo off
set CONSUMER=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

set AUTH="Authorization:Basic %CONSUMER%"
set ROLE="Role-Type:TERCEIROS"
set CONTENT="Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
set GRANT="grant_type=client_credentials"
set CERT=--cert-type P12 --cert certificate.pfx:xxxxxx
set URL="https://example.com/authenticate"

@echo on
curl -X POST -H %AUTH% -H %ROLE% -H %CONTENT% -d %GRANT% %CERT% %URL% -o auth\auth.txt

I am trying to convert this command above to node.js using the axios lib:
const axios = require("axios");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const consumer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const url      = "https://example.com/authenticate";

const data = {
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
};

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  pfx: fs.readFileSync("./certificate.pfx"),
  passphrase: "xxxxxx"
});

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']   = "Basic " + consumer;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Role-Type']       = "Third";
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var results = axios.post(url, {
  data: data,
  httpsAgent: httpsAgent
})
.then((res) => console.log(res.data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

But I am receiving the error message: certificate not found.
It seens that the way that I am inserting the certificate into the axios request is not the same way that the curl uses. How to do this? What is the Curl equivalent "--cert-type P12 --cert certificate.pfx:xxxxxx" in Axios?
